# Error trying to connect to cockroachdb with geography datatype from typeorm

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm, cockroachdb

While trying to connect to cockroach DB with column `geography`, I'm getting the following error

```
Unable to connect to the database: DataTypeNotSupportedError: Data type "geography" in "Club.latlon" is not supported by "cockroachdb" database.
```

While scouting the [docs](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/spatial-glossary.html#data-types) for cockroach DB I see the `geography` data type is supported.

Is cockroach DB with GIS not supported in typeorm?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TypeORM has an out-of-date [list of supported types](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/d305e5f9ac431f9b38a21e493886bf4836daa488/src/driver/cockroachdb/CockroachDriver.ts) for CockroachDB. TypeORM's Postgres driver *does* support geography, though, and you might be able to use that instead of the CockroachDB driver, either globally or just when interacting with spatial data, since CockroachDB is mostly compatible with Postgres drivers.